# Pass an id through the url in php codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, uri

I am trying to pass the page id through the url Here is my code,problem is i will not get the required page id to the page only get the path . Please help.
View Page

```
<li>
<a href="view/page_id=$page_id"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 1</a>        
</li>
<li>
<a href="view1/page_id=$page_id"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 2</a>                            
</li>
```

Controller Page

```
public function view()
{
echo $page_id =$this->uri->segment(1); 
$this->load->helper('url');
$data['offers_name'] = $this->Login_set->get_offer($id);
$data['offers_description'] = $data['offers_name']['offers_description'];
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_offers.php');
} 
public function view1()
{
echo $page_id =$this->uri->segment(2);
$this->load->helper('url');
$data['offers_name'] = $this->Login_set->get_offer($id);
$data['offers_description'] = $data['offers_name']['offers_description'];
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel2_offers.php');
}
```

Comment: <li>
<a href="view/<?php echo $page_id;?>"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 1</a>        
</li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<li>
<a href="view/page_id=$page_id"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 1</a>        
</li>
<li>
<a href="view1/page_id=$page_id"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 2</a>                            
</li>
```

into this:

```
<li>
<a href="view/<?php echo $page_id ?>"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 1</a>        
</li>
<li>
<a href="view1/<?php echo $page_id ?>"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 2</a>                            
</li>
```

Add `$this->uri->segment('segment_number')` in your controller to get the value from url

```
public function view()
{
    $page_id =$this->uri->segment(3); 

    $data['offers_name'] = $this->Login_set->get_offer($id);
    $data['offers_description'] = $data['offers_name']['offers_description'];
    $this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_offers.php');
//I put your codes here because you want Spoon Feed
} 
   public function view1()
   {
        $page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
       ...//rest of your codes here
   }
```

Comment: How come?? Did you try it??

Comment: You should check it before you comment that  it's not working.

Comment: Maybe the error is in your part, I used that way many times and your the only one who told me that there's an error..  JUST CHECK IT BRO,

Comment: I think page_id is a variable not a constant . so change `<?php echo page_id ?>` to `<?php echo $page_id ?>`,

Comment: It's already like that I don't know what he wants. It's his part Not mine! lol

Comment: I help him already but no one thank me. It is right but he keeps saying its wrong without checking his codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as url parameter

```
<li>
<a href="view/$page_id"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Hotel 1</a>        
</li>
```

And can access like this in controller

```
public function view($page_id)
{
    echo $page_id;
}
```

you can load helper in controller constructor

```
function __construct() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```